# Why did the past tense ending -t change to -ed?

Tags: orthography, archaicisms, historical-change, language-change

My posts are often questions for further knowledge about reasons for language change. In this extract from 1750, there are three variations on the past tense form. Once again, I am grateful if anyone can assist with explaining why or when contemporary use became standard practice.

> It appeared that the Priſoner went to the Proſecutors Shop and
>   cheapen’d ſome Handkerchiefs, that he carry’d one to the Door to ſhew
>   to a Woman who was there, and asked her if ſhe liked it; and as ſoon
>   as he was gone they miſt the Handkerchiefs off the Compter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, even verbs are subject to Darwin's idea of "survival of the fittest". Some highly irregular forms simply couldn't compete with simpler, newer forms. For example: dreamt and dreamed.

The form "dreamt" doesn't only require a spelling change--it also necessitates a pronunciation shift in the stem of the word--that's one change too many, and in evolutionary terms, this is expensive. "Dreamed" is simply a much more practical and more convenient choice. we simple just "ed", and We don't have to change the pronunciation of the stem. This explains the waning popularity of "dreamt" (and similar verbs like leant).

You can read this article for more ideas: http://notexactlyrocketscience.wordpress.com/2007/10/10/the-evolution-of-the-past-tense-%E2%80%93-how-verbs-change-over-time/

Comment: ***Leant*** may be out of the picture, but I'm still perfectly happy to write ***dreamt*** and ***learnt***. They reflect what I normally *say*, and I see no reason why orthography should be "standardised" where it doesn't reflect pronunciation. And I certainly don't expect ***lent*** and ***spent*** to fall into line any time soon.

Comment: And yet the record shows that the use of "dreamt" is fading out of the language. http://grammarist.com/usage/dreamed-dreamt/ I, too, like using "dreamt"--but people like ourselves have always been in the minority since 1800, and, I'm afraid, we've recently become an endangered species.

Comment: @ Louel: No question but that we're in a declining minority with *dreamt/learnt*. Personally, unless I was singing along with Joan Baez to ["I Dreamed I Saw Joe Hill Last Night"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_f2J4ceCikI) I wouldn't be likely to have a /d/ at the end. And the only context where I'd reflect the spelling of *learned* would be in, say, a *learned professor*, where there' be two syllables anyway. But I'm not a complete reactionary - I'm quite happy with forms like *dialog, epilog*, even if AmE still clings to the *-ogue* versions (but even I can't accept *prolog, monolog* yet :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers could a "complete reactionary" sing along to a song about Joe Hill? (or am I reactionary to bristle at your not citing Earl Robinson's version, since it was he who first put Alfred Hayes' poem to music?).

Answer (score -1):

A basic rule of thumb for words ending in "ed" is the following:  If a word ends in a voiced consonant (vowels are also voiced) then you use the "d" sound.  played (playd), bugged, learned, called (all end with "d" sound because the vowel (long a), the "g," "r," and "l" are all voiced.

Words that end in voiceless consonants will use the "t" sound.
jumped (jumpt), washed (washt) because "p" and "sh" are voiceless--they get a "t" sound at the end.

Words that already end in "t" or "d" would sound dumb if you tried that rule with them.  So we use the "ed" ending pronounced "id."

Deeded, texted, breaded (deedid, textid, breadid)

There are those pesky words like crooked which you find in nursery rhymes (Crooked (crookid) man) but can also be used as "He crooked (crookt) his finger at me to follow him through the forest."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with your answer...it's just you are answering the wrong question. The post was about the conversion of an irregular verb ending in 't', and how it became so.  BTW If you intend  to discuss pronunciation, here at EL&U I suggest that you become familiar with I[PA (International Phonetics Alphabet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) protocol.